# How can I get my bootstrap column to extend indefinitely (no height limit)?

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap row/col classes. It looks fine when the columns have very little content:

[image]

...but if they have a little more content (as "Delivery Performance" does in the screenshot below), the last element ("March 29, 2016 to April 5, 2016") in col 1 wraps up to where col 2 should be:

[image]

I want everything between "Delivery Performance" (all the links I dynamically add) to remain below the "Delivery Performance" h2, and never move to the next column. What do I need to do to achieve that?

Here is what I am doing (it's the same code - except for the column name/type specific parts - for all columns):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-3\">"); // <= begin col div
builder.Append("<h2>Delivery Performance</h2>");
builder.Append("<p></p>");

// Create links for each report
foreach (String fileBaseName in _FileBaseNameList)
{
    startDateYYYYMMDD = GetElement(3, fileBaseName);
    endDateYYYYMMDD = GetElement(4, fileBaseName);
    builder.Append("<p></p>");
    builder.Append(string.Format("<a 
        href=\"deliveryperformance/{0}/{1}/{2}\">{3}</a>", unit,  
        startDateYYYYMMDD,
        endDateYYYYMMDD, fileBaseName));                                                        
    builder.Append("</div>"); // <= end "col-md-3" div
    builder.Append("<p></p>");
}
return builder.ToString();
```

Do I need to add another class to the "column" div to set height to max or a gazillion, or what?

Comment: ist JavaScript `new StringBuilder()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the closing div outside of your for loop.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-3\">"); // <= begin col div
builder.Append("<h2>Delivery Performance</h2>");
builder.Append("<p></p>");

// Create links for each report
foreach (String fileBaseName in _FileBaseNameList)
{
    startDateYYYYMMDD = GetElement(3, fileBaseName);
    endDateYYYYMMDD = GetElement(4, fileBaseName);
    builder.Append("<p></p>");
    builder.Append(string.Format("<a 
        href=\"deliveryperformance/{0}/{1}/{2}\">{3}</a>", unit,  
        startDateYYYYMMDD,
        endDateYYYYMMDD, fileBaseName));                                                        
    builder.Append("<p></p>");
}
builder.Append("</div>"); // <= end "col-md-3" div
return builder.ToString();
```

If the empty paragraph tags are for styling I would recommend using css to add padding or margins to your elements for spacing instead. Though if you will be listing multiple reports an unordered list would be great here.